# Availability of Ethereum Snapshots for Fast Node Sync

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am setting up an Ethereum full node using Geth and looking for a way to speed up the initial sync process. I've come across discussions about using Ethereum snapshots, which are pre-synced blockchain data snapshots that can be used to bootstrap a new node.

However, I have been unable to find any official Ethereum snapshots available for download. My searches in various Ethereum communities and repositories did not yield any concrete results. I am wondering if Ethereum snapshots are officially provided or if there are any trusted sources to obtain them.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on whether Ethereum snapshots are available for syncing a new node, and if so, where they can be obtained. If official snapshots do not exist, are there any recommended alternatives or best practices for speeding up the initial sync process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I have been unable to find any official Ethereum snapshots available for download.

[Snap sync](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/sync-modes) is built into GoEthereum. It is also enabled by default.

You do not need any centralised downloads to snap sync your GoEthereum full node.